# Python-pptx compatibility with text boxes in LibreOffice

Tags: python, textbox, libreoffice, python-pptx

Just starting to try to use python-pptx, and have fallen at the first. Linux Mint 20.1, python 3.85, LibreOffice 6.4.

This is basically the 'Hello World' from the documentation.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt

prs = Presentation()
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)

left = top = width = height = Inches(1)
txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left, top, width, height)
tf = txBox.text_frame

print('before text ', txBox.left, txBox.top, txBox.width, txBox.height)
tf.text = "This is a long line of text inside a textbox"
print('after text ', txBox.left, txBox.top, txBox.width, txBox.height)

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

The text is more than a single line for the textbox. Printing out its bounds before and after text insertion shows that as far as python-pptx is concerned, the textbox width hasn't changed.

When the resulting presentation is viewed in LibreOffice, instead of wrapping the text within its boundaries, the textbox has expanded symmetrically around the mid point, pushing the start of the text off the lefthand edge of the page.

I was hoping the LibreOffice was only incompatible with powerpoint for rare edge cases, but text in text boxes is the meat and bread of presentations.

When I upload it to google slides, the text wraps within the left and right text box boundaries, but spills out of the bottom edge. The textbox shows up as 1" x 1" in the right place.

If I use onedrive.live.com, the text is left justified in the box and spills out of the righthand side without wrapping, and the textbox is shown as being 1" x 1" in the right place.

If I use onlinedocumentviewer.com, the display is the same as onedrive, though I can't get to see the text box.

Unfortunately I can't test the behaviour on a native powerpoint installation.

Maybe there's an autosize or fixed flag, which left unset leaves each viewer defaulting it in its own idiosyncratic way? How do we control text boxes / frames when targetting LibreOffice?

I possibly have a workaround to break up my text into single lines and use one per text box, but I'd rather understand the whether it can be done the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

After some floundering around in the docs, I stumbled across the text_frame .word_wrap property. Setting to True gets the text to wrap in LibreOffice. While I was there, setting text_frame.auto_size = MSO_AUTO_SIZE.TEXT_TO_FIT_SHAPE reduces font size to get it all to fit in the box.

Is there a list of properties like .word_wrap in one place anywhere?

Comment: Do you mean like here: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#textframe-objects ? In general this sort of thing is what API documentation is; all the objects and all the things each one knows (attributes) and what they can do (methods).

Comment: @scanny No, I'd not been on that page before. In fact, once I'd clicked off it, I couldn't find out how to navigate there from the top-level. I did wonder why there was so little documentation. I'll take some time to map out what's there to try to find my way around, go back there and leave some breadcrumbs. I'm not usually forced into introspection, so that's taken some time to figure out, print(dir(textframe)). Thanks for an excellent library, there's no question that pptx will be the right vehicle to automate my presentation needs, once I have found all the docs.

Comment: Finding the documentation is something that comes up pretty much every time one considers or uses a new library. A Google search of `python-pptx documentation` brings up the link as the first result in this case. That's my first move on a new library and that seems to work 99% of the time. Next in line is PyPi for the library, https://pypi.org/project/python-pptx/ in this case. That also has a link to the documentation above the fold, but not all do. Next stop is the GitHub repo: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx which in this case has a link to the docs on the home page.

Comment: If none of those work, well, some folks don't document their code and that would be a deal-breaker for me to use it, so I don't find myself there too often :)  I consider the documentation to be the "contract" with the user for what the library will do for them, and if it isn't there, it's a pretty dicey situation and almost surely not a library I want to build other things on top of.

Comment: Btw @Niel_UK you provided some very helpful answers for questions of mine over on EE SO, thanks again for those and glad for any opportunity to return the favor :)

Comment: @scanny I started on readthedocs.io, and hit the hello worlds (HWs). Can I offer a noob's perspective? The text HW breaks Least Astonishment. A HW should work as is. Big text into a small box breaks, and breaks differently on different renderers, obviously they inherit from different defaults. I panicked, and wasn't able properly to navigate the remaining complete, but dense, documentation (Sphinx is a mixed blessing). With the textbox HW, you should mention the behaviour up front, the different renderers, and link directly to the text properties, my confidence one hour in was very knocked.